# View all available application in an erlang installation

Tags: compilation, erlang

If I want to know if erlang was compiled with ssl support I do :

1> ssl:versions().

But how to view the list of available application that were included at compilation time ? I need to as access to the list to include it in an installation checklist.

Thanks to all

Comment: Does this `file:list_dir_all(code:lib_dir())` help?

Comment: Yes thanks for this trick, even if code:lib_dir() only return the system libdir and do not include additionnal dirs pass with ERL_LIBS, I'll merge the lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `application` module to do this:

```
$ erl
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.9.3.1  (abort with ^G)
1> application:which_applications().
[{stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.18.3"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.15.3"}]
```

Comment: That will return only the running applications